# Filtering unique records of a table widget datasource based on a single column in Google AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a one-to-many relation, and I want to retrieve the "many" from a "one", however I am interested in only a single column of the "many" and although the records are unique the value of that column might not and I want to get the rows corresponding to the unique values of that column, possibly the first row in order of appearance (it doesn't really matter).

I added a table widget and added some code in the `onDataLoad`:

```
var items = widget.datasource.items;
var uniqueItems = [];
var keys = new Set();
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
  if (!keys.has(items[i].Address))
  {
    uniqueItems.push(items[i]);
    keys.add(items[i].Address);
  }
}
widget.datasource.items = uniqueItems;
```

Here the column of interest is Address. The point was to go through the records and keep track of unique Address values, and whenever a new Address is encountered, keep it, and finally set the datasource to the unique list of rows that was just built.

It's not working. The keys are unique, but it is failing to set the datasource.

I am missing possibly more than one thing. Possible things that are happening:

1. This code shouldn't be in `onDataLoad`
2. This code actually sets the datasource but it is not reflected in the table
3. Wrong data type for `uniqueItems`
4. You can't just set a datasource
5. Bug I haven't seen...

How can I have my unique set appear in the table?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use a standard datasource to set your items like this. You would want to look at possibly a client calculated datasource or a regular calculated datasource using a server script. You may also be able to use a calculated SQL datasource as long as there is a SQL query that supports only looking for unique values.

Comment: Thank you @MarkusMalessa for pointing this out. I ended up using a radio group with a modified version of my client side script. could I have also used a List widget I suppose, but I am new to all this. I need to look into calculated datasources.